# Wireless internet connection wont work on dell n4010 on ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: wireless

I just recently installed Ubuntu on my Dell N4010 but I can not connect to the internet with WiFi. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: What is the output of `lspci | grep Network`?

Answer (score -1):

Like Seth said in his comment above. Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type in the following at the prompt:

```
$ lspci | grep Network
```

That will tell you what wireless adapter you're running, at which point you can do a quick Google search to find the Linux drivers (assuming you have another machine capable of connecting to the internet).

Comment: -1 Not much of an answer. Googling a problem is probably first solution and people come to Ask Ubuntu once unable to solve it by googling